# Pulling Hyperledger Fabric chaincode related image from a private registry

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

For the chaincode instantiation we pull the images dynamically from the docker hub. However, let's say if I have chaincode related images (e.g. fabric-ccenv, fabric-baseos, etc.) on a private registry, then how shall the peer code *validate or authenticate* to the registry? Is there any setting in core.yaml or other configuration changes that we can make to achieve that?

Comment: Please refer to this thread https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-8559

Comment: I referred to the JIRA thread. However, I still feel, they have not addressed the issue of peer pulling the image from a private registry. I cannot see a configuration while creating peer node, that will allow the peer to authenticate to a private registry. I do know that we can pull from any public registry (by setting some env variables) but, I think it is not configurable to use a private registry.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no mechanism in the `core.yaml` to specify credentials for a private registry, using the new `External Builder and Launcher` chaincode model, you can tell the Peer exactly how to build/compile/pull/run/connect to chaincode, thus allowing you to tell the peer how to connect to the private registry and pull your image. You can find instructions on configuring your own external builder in our doc here where you can use absolutely any mechanism you want for running chaincode: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/cc_launcher.html

Comment: Thanks but we currently support and provide HLF 1.4.4 as a service. Sorry, I just forgot to add that in question.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is there is no way to do this in 1.4. As this would be a new feature we wouldn't target something like this for `1.4.x` anyway, as the 1.4 is in LTS maintenance and new features are only targeted for 2.x.